# How do I add a method to immutable-js Map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, flowtype, immutable.js

I wanted to add a really simple method to immutable js to ease debugging...

```
log(msg) {
  console.log(msg, this.toJS());
  return this;
}
```

Essentially so I could use it to debug chained expressions like:

```
someImmutableMap
  .toList()
  .slice(index, index + ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
  .filter(index => !!index)
  .log('Filter: ')
  .map(griddleMapper)
  .toJS()
```

Does something like this already exist? If not, how do I add it to the `Map` class in order that I can raise a pull request?

I've tried adding it to `src/Map.js` inside the `Map` class definition and adding simple test for it but the test fails with `Property 'log' does not exist on type 'Map<string, number>'.`

I suspect that's because I need to define the type in `type-definitions` but I've never used typescript / flow etc so I'm completely lost.

[Here](https://github.com/bristoljon/immutable-js) is my forked repo with the basic changes I've made above..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Generally adding functions to types you don't own is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

you *could* extend Collection's prototype (the base type) like so:

```
Immutable.Collection.prototype.log = function(msg){
    console.log(msg, this.toJS());
    return this;
};
```

or in es6 class style, just move your `log()` method over [here](https://github.com/bristoljon/immutable-js/blob/ac6e319c7cf07805698b0ade9d045494fec6b404/src/Collection.js#L16). but as loganfsmyth noted above it's generally frowned upon since it often leads to confusion and compatibility issues.

another option is to just make a helper fn like:

```
function logImmutable(msg, obj){
    console.log(msg, obj.toJS());
    return obj;
}
```

then you'd call it like:

```
logImmutable('Filter', someImmutableMap
    .toList()
    .slice(index, index + ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    .filter(index => !!index)) // note the extra paren :-P
    .map(griddleMapper)
    .toJS();
```

though i'd agree that developer ux and overall readability suffer.

yet another option would be to use something like https://github.com/mattzeunert/immutable-object-formatter-extension which extends the base `console.log()` behavior such that it can better deal with immutable.js objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I maybe wasn't clear but what I'd like to do is raise a pull request on immutable-js with the change so that it might potentially be added to the library officially as a new feature.

I was going to raise an issue on the github repo with the suggestion but it advises making a pull request for them to review which is where I got stuck due to type script unfamiliarity.

I thought it could be a useful feature for other users..

Comment: Your `logImmutable` function is a good intermediate solution though, thanks